# My stock is too sweet

Tags: stock

As part of my Thanksgiving preparation, I made a chicken and turkey stock by first roasting the bones and then cooking them very low for a few hours. About an hour or so before the end of their cooking, I added roasted vegetables -- a combination of onion, carrot, celery, parsnip, turnip, and parsley root. I didn't add any other flavoring other than a touch of salt. (I know most people don't salt their stocks, but I tend to undersalt everything, so adding it at every step will help.)

My stock is tasty, but rather sweet. Is this a factor of too many sweet vegetables (or not enough celery)? Or is there something else I'm missing?

(I compensated in my gravy by adding a touch of soy sauce and fish sauce to add more umami flavoring. But I'd like to understand why it happened.)

Comment: Roasted onions and carrots are usually very sweet! It depends upon the quantity you used ...

Comment: It's the parsnips.  I chop them small and add them to the soup as vegetables near the end rather than adding them as aromatics to the stock.

Comment: I really recommend not salting stock.  It is *so* easy to add later if you're making soup or sauce, but impossible to remove if you're making a risotto or anything that doesn't need salt.

Comment: I don't think I ever want to eat risotto cooked with unsalted stock.

Comment: @vwiggins: Is that supposed to be a joke?  No risotto recipe I have ever seen calls for salt during the cooking process, just as a seasoning later, and the ones that include broth as a liquid ingredient (as opposed to stock or water or wine) usually make a point of mentioning the *low-salt* type.

Comment: @Aaronut While I agree with checking the seasoning later I've found when you know some salt needs adding you're best getting it in as early in the cooking process as possible as then you need less over all. A "touch of salt" in the stock means you can get a full profile of the stock's flavour before adding it to the risotto. Completely unsalted chicken stock for instance tastes of nothing. The exception might be if the sheer quantity of salt in the risotto's additions (like a greater than usual proportion of cheese) would bring the salt levels too high.

Comment: @vwiggins: Completely unsalted chicken stock does *not* "tastes of nothing".  If yours is tasteless then you're making it wrong.  Adding salt early *is* a good idea in many cases, but stock is not one of them.  There is no appreciable difference in flavour if you add the salt to the stock while you're making it or add it just before you use it in some other dish.  If you can find one prominent expert who says to salt stock, I will eat my hat.

Comment: Veggies don't need to be roasted for making stock.  What's happening is that you are drawing out and caramelizing the sugars in the onions and carrots, especially, when you roast them.  Try to just add the raw vegetables, at the very start, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some vegetables are aromatics for infusing flavor without changing the underlying base, and certain combinations become known for cuisines.  Onion, celery and carrots make mire-poix.  Onions, garlic and tomato make sofrito.

Turnips and parsnips are not those kinds of vegetables, usually.  Parsnips get very sweet (a good thing usually) as do onions and carrots.  You just combined a lot of the ones that get sweet and intensified it by roasting.

If you are looking for a more neutral broth, stay with onions, celery and carrots and simmer, don't roast.

Comment: Anytime you roast your veggies they will get sweeter.  So if you want to keep your stock less sweet, use raw veggies.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I added turnips and parsnips because I like them. Same with the parsley root. :-) But maybe next time I should not roast the parsnips.

Comment: @Martha: Don't roast *any* of the vegetables, otherwise you don't have a true mirepoix.  In addition you should use a 2:1:1 ratio (50% onion, 25% carrot and 25% celery).  If you up the carrots too much, it'll be too sweet even without roasting.

Comment: @Aaronaut - I think you're on to something with the carrots. They were actually pretty huge, I had to chop them in half lengthwise, so they'd fit in the oven. (Yes, I helped Martha make the stock.)

Comment: @Aaronaut -- is it important to have a true mirepoix? I'm not trying to make a traditional stock, necessarily. Just one that tastes good.

Comment: @Martha: Well, not necessarily, I guess, but mirepoix is to stock as roux is to white sauce.  It's kind of fundamental (along with the bouquet garni), and generally you don't mess with it unless you have a lot of experience and know exactly what you're trying to do.  And even then, people typically just *add* to it, and you have to be careful what you add (as Doug has pointed out, parsnips aren't really appropriate for most stocks).  So while there's always more than one way to skin a cat in cooking, you should probably stick with the "standard" for stock unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: P.S. @Martha, there's no "A" in the middle of my name; I won't get your comment replies if it's spelled wrong. ;)

Comment: @Aaronut -- Ah, okay. Thanks for the explanation! (And all I need to remember is that you're a nut, not a space case. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The size, or surface area, of the vegetables makes a difference as well.  Carrots chopped too small will make a stock overly sweet.  And as others have said, use raw vegetables.

Comment: That certainly can happen, although they have to be *really* finely chopped for it to be a problem; fine enough to actually break down and dissolve during the simmering, almost a minced consistency.  The standard 1/2" cube works well.

Comment: @Aaronut True, should have specified a size in my comment.

Comment: Makes sense, but this wasn't the problem in this case. I had quite large pieces.